# After Axios request my React state is still empty

Tags: reactjs, axios

So I have Axios request witch takes some specific accounts and I want them to populate my React state array, but it always stays empty

```js
function App() {
  const twitchAccounts = ["passhtet", "dallas", "bobross", "riotgames"];
  const [live, setLive] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    for (let index = 0; index < twitchAccounts.length; index++) {
      axios
        .get(
          `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?&user_login=${twitchAccounts[index]}`
        )
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.data.data.length > 0) {
            return live.push(res.data.data);
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }, []);

  console.log(live, "live");
  return <div />
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure your'e getting a response, btw not sure if you can use push on state try using setLive function

Comment: Gayatri Dipali  yeah I am getting response, just can't populate array with response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, you should be using **Promise.all**.

setState is async, and setting state in a loop is not recommended and may produce undesirable behavior (e.g. order of the results may not be the same since axios.get is async and may returned at different timings OR you state may get overwritten by incoming setState when both one or more methods are setting state at the same time)

By using Promise.all, i get all the results in parallel, and I ensure I set the correct results in state.

```
 React.useEffect(() => {

    const initialize = async() => {
        const results = await Promise.all(twitchAccounts.map(item => {
              return axios.get(
          `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?&user_login=${item}`
        )
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.data.data.length > 0) {
            return res.data.data
          }
          return null
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
 
        }))
        setLive(results)
    }

initialize()
}, []);
```

the `live` state is also saved in the same order as your twitchAccounts

Comment: Not sure why but I am getting all results undefined.

Comment: You need to console.log (res.data.data) and see what is it, because I do not know what twitch.tv returns. You may want to try return `res.data` as well. I've also edited the code, I believe you need to add a `return` before axios

Comment: This is the working codebox (i replaced axios with `new Promise` to mimick promise behavior) - https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-heisenberg-6xsh2?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

React rules state that when making changes to a state object, you must use setState. In your case, this would be

```
if (res.data.length > 0) {
  return setLive([...live, res.data.data])
}
```

It is possible that the console.log(live) gets triggered before the api result is received. Try to wrap the console.log(live) in a setTimeout to confirm this.

Comment: It still returns empty array, but if I do  return setLive(res.data.data) I get at least one data in array, but still would be awesome to populate all array with possible results. Have no idea why its not populating.

Comment: I played a bit around, sometimes it populates with one value but sometimes more than two.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to send multiple requests and want to populate after all the requests are done. But there are some issues there:

1. You didn't updated the state
2. If you update the state after each request completes, you have to know that, the component will also `rerenders` after updating the state, which leads to a very slow website.
3. After all, we are using an async environment.

So, the solution can be, `wait for each request to end`, `push the response in a temporary array`, and `after all the requests are done, push the whole array in the state`. That will update the state once.

So here is a `useEffect` that will help you

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
      const data = await Promise.all(twitchAccounts.map(item => {
        axios.get(
          `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?&user_login=${item}`
        )
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.data.data.length > 0) {
            return res.data.data
          }
          return null
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
 
      }))
      setLive(prev => [...prev, ...data])
    })();
    
  }, []);
```